# Swift - Formatting text field error in viewDidLoad() w/ VSTextField.swift

Tags: xcode, swift, formatting, textfield

While trying to set formatting for a phone number text field using [VSTextField](https://github.com/VojtaStavik/VSTextField), I got the error below:

[Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUXCz.png)

I assumed viewDidLoad was the best location to put it, but it doesn't seem to work.  I am not sure where to put the phoneNumber.setFormatting() statement so that the text field will function correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Silly question: did you connect the outlet?

Comment: Yes the outlet is connected haha.  Idk what to do:(